# Chrome запуск в новом окне с отключенным звуком

Tags: google-chrome

Собственно, открыть страницу в новом окне можно так -

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" "https://
www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4" --mute-audio --new-window
```

Но звук все равно воспроизводится...

Answer (score 3):

[Список команд](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) запуска для chrome. 
`--mute-audio` присутствует, но не отрабатывает.
Даже при включенном флаге `chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting`.

Еще нашел сочетания клавиш.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> - отключить звук на активной вкладке.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> - отключить звук на всех открытых вкладках.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> - включить звук на всех открытых вкладках.

Answer (score 2):

1.Ну можешь замутить chrome то замути тупо видео без звука )))
2.Создай HTML страницу туда ставь видео с ютуба и параметр volume="0" таким образом будет без звука.